# Linker does not want to use libexpat.so (undefined symbol)

Tags: linker

I'm trying to compile a program (not written by me) in Kubuntu 12.04 and it fails with the following:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_baseu_xml-2.8.so: undefined reference to symbol 'XML_SetUserData'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'XML_SetUserData' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I fixed a couple of mistakes in the `Makefile`, but I still don't understand what's the problem here, as the command line does include `-lexpat`, and apparently at the correct location:

```
g++ [...] -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu [...] -lwx_baseu_xml-2.8 [...] -lm -lexpat [...]
```

How could I fix/debug this?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `-v -Wl,-v` to the flags allowed me to see the command lines for `collect2` and `ld`.

For some reason, the original `Makefile` was putting the libraries (`-L` and `-l` options) before most of the object files. I put the libraries at the end of the command line and now it compiles.